Index notation for the generalized form of the velocity gradient with shear and rotation
Good day guys, I was studying fluid dynamics and came across the following equations (shown in the image):
When we have both shear and and rotation, they each contribute to the change in velocity field by adding their contributions. The shear components of the strain-rate tensor, and the vector components of the rotation/angular velocity vector. The LHS of the equations looks good to me, but fail to see why using index notation it would be written as the RHS, which uses two indices for the rotation vector, is it a mistake?


It doesn't seem to be a mistake. We use similar notation in relativity. It means that
$$\omega_{xy} = \omega_z,$$
and so on. The general expression, as pointed out in a comment to this answer, is
$$\omega_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^3 \epsilon_{ijk} \omega_k,$$
with $\epsilon_{ijk}$ the Levi-Civita symbol. This is easier to generalize to larger dimensions, but probably the interest in here is getting a simpler expression.

Yes, just to elaborate, there is an implicit definition $\omega_{ij} = \epsilon_{ijk}\omega_k $ here, where $\epsilon$ is the Levi-Civita symbol.

@Puk Indeed. I incorporated your suggestion in the answer

Thank you so much guys, so we basically increase the rank of the tensor. What about permutations such as  $i=1$ and $j=3$, this would give $\omega_{12} = \epsilon_{132}\omega_{2} = -\omega_{y}$. Should it not be $+\omega_y$ ?

@RMS No. $\omega_{zx} = - \omega_{xz} = \omega_{y}$. The order matters. Also, notice we are increasing the order, but keeping the number of degrees of freedom fixed.

@NíckolasAlves Thank you for all your help. Is the reason behind $\omega_{zx} = -\omega_{xz}$ that a rotation/cross product from z to x points in the +y-direction, while the rotation from x to z, points in the -y-direction ?

@RMS I never thought of it that way (I actually never thought much about it), but yes, that seems right. I actually prefer the cross product argument, because the cross product is exactly written with the Levi-Civita symbol in a similar way, but I think the rotation argument is equivalent
